# Как правильно задать время при загрузки в БД с помощью файла командой psql \i в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

столкнулся с такой "проблемой". Я загружаю с помощью psql \i 'path/file.sql' в БД, где четко указываю в запросе задавать время по CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (оно же +0 по UTC), но оно почему-то подтягивает мое текущее время, а уже последующие манипуляции в базе берутся по CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
Кто сталкивался с такой ситуацией? Как можно задать, чтобы с консольки задавало время CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, а не мое текущее

UPD: вопрос решен. К CURRENT_TIMESTAMP добавляем at time one 'UTC' - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC'

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP никак не привязан к UTC, наоборот, это именно время начала транзакции в `timestamp with time zone`.

Comment: @Мелкий А можно свести к единому времени? Так как, когда я с консоли (psql) вызываю оно мне допусти дает время 14:00, а когда делаю эту же операцию уже в самой базе, то время 11:00  будет. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp without time zone` не помогает

Comment: что такое "в самой базе"? В смысле в чем отличие от psql? Если в одном клиенте время в одной таймзоне, а в другом - другая - то и итог логичный, разный timezone у вас. Это одноимённая настройка в соединении